# memory usage in Python with a class with a large size array

Tags: python, class, oop, memory, numpy-ndarray

I have a class:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

class example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = np.random.rand(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)

    def f(self, a):
        return self.arr[0, 1, 2, 3] * a

s = example()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with Pool(8) as po:
        x = po.map(s.f, range(100))
```

Since I have a huge numpy array `arr` in my `class example`. And I have a method which call this `arr` to do some calculations. Then I initialize the class and call the method `f` 100 times. In that case,

1. The memory usage of my program is mostly that of the big `arr` plus some small head-off but negligible
2. Or, it is 100 times that of the memory size of arr plus some small head-off since I call `s.f` 100 times?

I run a similar problem in the high-performance computing facility but found that the memory usage is much much greater than that of `arr`. Not known why.

I firmly believe that 1 is correct. But the final result prefers 2?

Comment: You've got some other issue. I'm going to guess your real program uses `multiprocessing`, and you're getting mixed up by all the implicit copies that involves, but that's just a guess. We can't tell what's really going on.

Comment: Each time you call the `.f()` method, a brand-new array is created, holding the results of the calculation.  All of those arrays are kept alive in memory, due to the fact that you've appended all of them to the `c` list.  So at the end, you have 101 arrays in memory.

Comment: @jasonharper `f()` doesn't create a new array, it just indexes a single element in `self.arr`.

Comment: `s.arr` is using 8 terabytes of memory all by itself. I'm surprised you're able to create that.

Comment: @user2357112, thanks. I indeed used multiprocessing. And the description of the problem is changed accordingly. In that case, could you please explain why memory raises highly?

Comment: @jasonharper, thanks. But arr is just an attribute of the class. Once I initialised the class example with the instance s, then arr is already initialised. When I call functions within the class which use arr to perform computations, why does it repeatedly re-create arr?

Comment: @Barmar, just an example. Not 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 in practical. It seems that you support 1 but not 2. Is that correct?

Comment: @John I didn't notice the `po.map()` earlier, I now agree with the other commenters about the copies of the array. To avoid this you would need to use shared memory -- Python multiprocessing doesn't do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Save for other frameworks which might change the way the program runs (for example, 3rd party logging libraries which will instrument your code), this code will behave like this:

For each process in the multiprocessing Pool it will create all its data. So, with a Pool of "8" and the mapping bellow, it will take 8 times the `self.arr` size - if you don't create new `example` class instances in your code: each process in the pool will have one `example` instance. And beyond that each time you call `f` it will compute a new array with the size it takes in the calculation.

The `multiprocessing.Pool.map` code will run the tasks as fast as possible, when you take one result from `x`, while you are processing it in your main code, the background processes will be generating the new items and placing it in a queue so that they are ready. In other words: depending on how long it takes to process each item of `x` (and 100% sure if you transform `x` to a `list`), yes, you might get 100 copies of your `f` output, and in transient moments, even more: when using multiprocessing, there is an overhead in passing data back and forth - one might say that an original copy, an "in transit" copy, and a destination copy of the data will exist: so up to three times the value returned by `self.f` will exist at a time. (but you won't get "300" times the value returned by `f`. In your example code, that value is a small array, and it should be no problem - but if in your real code, the value returned by the function called in `.map` is big, that will be your problem.

Other than that, you have one copy of `self.arr` per process, as stated above.

The code can be changed so that instead of using a Poll.map, you just submit a new task to the multiprocessing worker when you are done with a value from a previous iteration.  You should change your code to use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `multiprocessing.Poll` directly, and call `submit` for the next iteration of `example.f` once you are done with a previous result of an `example.f` call.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

This code, to be done correctly, might be a bit more complicated, so I've worked on a template that should be good enough to get going:

```
import numpy as np
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, wait, FIRST_COMPLETED
#from multiprocessing import Pool

class example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = np.random.rand(100, 100, 100, 100)  # reduced from 1000,1000, 1000, 1000
                                                       # so we can locally test this

    def f(self, a):
        return self.arr[0, 1, 2, 3] * a

# one instance per worker is created with this at the top level!

def initializer(example_instance):
    global s
    # ensures the global variable "s"
    # points to a copy of the "example" instance in the root process
    s = example_instance

def do_it(data_point):
    # global s
    # prefer functions than methods when using multiprocessing, since
    # different instances will be present in different workers
    # ("self" will be "other self" in each worker)
    return s.f(data_point)

def main():

    workers = 8
    # creates ONE instance of "example" here!
    # It will be passed around to workers by the ProcessPoolExecutor call
    # (and one copy of each will live in each worker)
    s = example()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers, initializer=initializer, initargs=(s,)) as po:
        data = iter(range(100))   # iter wrapper around your data source: allows us to submit the initial
                                  # values, and later submit one new data_point at a time.
        # populate workers with initial data so they do their job:
        for i, data_point in zip(range(workers), data):
            futures = {po.submit(do_it, data_point)}
        while futures:
            done, pending = wait(futures, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
            # here "done" will contain one or more of the return values of example.f
            n_done = len(done)
            for future in done:
                result = future.result()
                # ***************************************************
                # core code to process result of example.f goes here!
                ...
                print(result)

            # Remove references to completed results so memory is freed up!
            del done, future, result
            for i in range(n_done):
                data_point = next(data, None)
                if data_point is None:
                    break # we are done submitting new tasks: the last
                          # needed calculation is already ongoing!
                # submit new tasks for execution just when we are one with
                # the previous batch
                pending.add(po.submit(do_it, data_point))
            futures = pending



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```